# Javascript: wrap matched regex with tags

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to surround dates in middleRsults with  tags:

```
var middleRsults = "95.00      04/07/15    aaaa  10/02/15 ";
var regex =/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/g;
var x= middleRsults.replace(regex,"<b>$1</b>")
```

What I want to get:

```
  95.00      <b>04/07/15</b>    aaaa  <b>10/02/15</b>
```

instead, what I actually get:

```
95.00      <b>$1</b>    aaaa  <b>$1</b>
```

I search a lot, but couldn't figure out why this is happening with this specific regex that I am using.

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) carefully to learn what `$1` means, and what other special replacement patterns are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current regular expression you can simply use the matched substring `$&`:

```js
var middleRsults = '95.00      04/07/15    aaaa  10/02/15 ',
    regex = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/g,
    x = middleRsults.replace(regex, '<b>$&</b>');

console.log(x);
```

Or, for more complex situations, you can specify a function as a parameter where `match` is the matched substring (Corresponds to $& above.):

```js
var middleRsults = '95.00      04/07/15    aaaa  10/02/15 ',
    regex = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/g,
    x = middleRsults.replace(regex, match => `<b>${match}</b>`);

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a *capturing group* to use the `$n` replacement:

```
var regex =/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})/g;
```

The parentheses form such a group. The groups are numbered left-to-right in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably face-palm when you realise this but your regex doesn't contain a capture group for $1 to refer to.

This should hopefully fix it:

```
var regex = /(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})/g;
```